# Upgrade JQuery version 3.2 typing file,it's throws lint error

Tags: angular, typescript

In my application, I have used the interface as like below.It's works fine in JQuery 2.0

```
interface JQuery{
data(key: any): any;
}
```

When upgrade a version to JQuery 3.2,It's throws the below lint errors.

**All declarations of 'JQuery' must have identical type parameters.
interface JQuery
namespace JQuery**

Typescript Version: 2.3

How to resolved the issue or modify the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of issue will be resolved by updating the Typescript Version to 3.x or higher.

Hope this helps to solve the issue.